# Can´t use data from a textarea and make an update Mongodb Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building a simple notes app using express and MongoDB and I got this kind of bug where I can't update the description of the Notes, just the Title. This the form from where I'm getting the data:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Edit Note</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/notes/edit-note/{{note._id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST" >
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text " class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="title" value="{{note.title}}">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <textarea name="decription" id="decription" style="width: 100%;" class="mt-4"placeholder="description">{{note.description}}</textarea>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think thats working fine cause when I `console.log(req.body)` I get the following:

> { _method: 'PUT', title: 'some text', decription: 'some text' }

Based on this I think the error might be on the JS

My Index.js is the following:

```
    const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//init
const app = express();
require("./database");
//settings
app.set("port", 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

//Middleware

app.set(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysecretapp",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

//Global varaibles

//routes
app.use(require("./routes/index"));
app.use(require("./routes/notes"));
app.use(require("./routes/users"));
//Static files

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//Server listening

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => console.log("App listening on port 3000!"));
```

My Schema is the following:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const NoteSchema=new Schema({
    title:{type: String, required:true},
    description:{type: String, required:true},
    date:{type: Date,default:Date.now},
})
module.exports= mongoose.model('Note',NoteSchema)
```

finally this is the code for the oruter from where in tryin to make the update

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Note = require("../models/Note");
router.put("/notes/edit-note/:id", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const title = req.body.title;
  const description = req.body.description;
  await Note.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { '$set': { title: title, description: description } }
  );
  res.redirect("/notes/notes");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error on

```
<textarea name="decription" id="decription" style="width: 100%;" class="mt-4"placeholder="description">{{note.description}}</textarea>
```

`name` should be 'description', that fixed the problem.